# Python Tkinter: El "/n" no funciona en mi .insert() de mi Text()

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un editor de codigo, y entonces quiero añadir Snippets (fragmentos de codigo) para que el usuario se ahorre tener que escribir toda la sentencia que necesite

Entonces, hice una funcion llamada `ifs()`:

```
def ifs():
    mesnajeTxt.insert(END, "if (// if this is true)/n{/n//code here/n}")
```

Pruebo el programa, y los "/n" (que sirven para dejar un renglon) no me funcionan ¿Acaso es un error o no se puede hacer eso en un `.insert()`? ¿Como hago que funcione?

Por si aun no quedo claro, quiero que se deje un espacio, para que el `Text()` (donde se escribe el codigo) quede asi:

```
if (// if this is true)
{
// code here
}
```

Si necesitas el codigo, deja un comentario y hago un edit

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: acaso no es `\n`?

Comment: No se si TKinter lo permite pero puedes usar la sintaxis de *doc-string*  que son 3 pares de comillas `""" """` y te permite escribir en varias líneas

Comment: Creo que el salto de linea es con \n.

Comment: Enserio es con \n? ahora lo pruebo gracias por opinar

Comment: Si, tienen razon, tkinter si lo permite pero lo estaba haciendo mal ¡Gracias!

Comment: @Christian se que hay cosas que no sabes de Tkinter, pero quitando el hecho de que el método insert es de Tkinter, el segundo argumento es un string, el cual tiene varias sintaxis en Python, incluyendo el que mencionaste de docstring. No importa lo que haga la función.

Comment: @DanteS. muchas gracias por las aclaraciones ^_^

Comment: Es un placer c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El salto de linea en python, aun y usando tkinter, es usando la contra barra \n, en este caso tendrás que cambiar /n por \n.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

**Solucionado**

La solucion es que yo lo estaba haciendo mal, no es `/n`, es `\n`

Muchas gracias a los comentarios ya que me han ayudado

Gracias y saludos.